# How does one lock specific array indices in multiprocessing package?

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I have a `multiprocessing.manager.Array` object that will be shared by multiple workers to tally observed events: each element in the array holds the tally of a different event type. Incrementing a tally requires both read and write operations, so I believe that to avoid race conditions, each worker needs to request a lock that covers both stages, e.g.

```
with lock:
    my_array[event_type_index] += 1
```

My intuition is that it should be possible to place a lock on a specific array element. With that type of lock, worker #1 could increment element 1 at the same time that worker #2 is incrementing element 2. This would be especially helpful for my application (*n*-gram counting), where the array length is quite large and collisions would be rare.

However, I can't figure out how to request an element-wise lock for an array. Does such a thing exist in `multiprocessing`, or is there a workaround?

For more context, I've included my current implementation below:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from queue import Empty

def count_ngrams_in_sentence(n, ngram_counts, char_to_idx_dict, sentence_queue, lock):
    while True:
        try:
            my_sentence_str = sentence_queue.get_nowait()
            my_sentence_indices = [char_to_idx_dict[i] for i in my_sentence_str]
            my_n = n.value
            for i in range(len(my_sentence_indices) - my_n + 1):
                my_index = int(sum([my_sentence_indices[i+j]*(27**(my_n - j - 1)) \
                                    for j in range(my_n)]))
                with lock:  # lock the whole array?
                    ngram_counts[my_index] += 1
            sentence_queue.task_done()
        except Empty:
            break
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = 4
    num_ngrams = 27**n
    num_workers = 2
    sentences = [ ... list of sentences in lowercase ASCII + spaces ... ]

    manager = mp.Manager()
    sentence_queue = manager.JoinableQueue()
    for sentence in sentences:
        sentence_queue.put(sentence)
    n = manager.Value('i', value=n, lock=False)
    char_to_idx_dict = manager.dict([(i,ord(i)-97) for i in string.ascii_lowercase] + [(' ', 26)],
                                    lock=False)
    lock = manager.Lock()
    ngram_counts = manager.Array('l', [0]*num_ngrams, lock=lock)
''
    workers = [mp.Process(target=count_ngrams_in_sentence,
                          args=[n,
                                ngram_counts,
                                char_to_idx_dict,
                                sentence_queue,
                                lock]) for i in range(num_workers)]
    for worker in workers:
        worker.start()
    sentence_queue.join()
```

Comment: Oh damn, I have a similar question. @mewahl did you make any progress?

Comment: Sorry to say I never solved this one, @mozboz -- better luck to you, though!

Comment: thanks for reply. I don't have a huge number of array elements so just went with separate array of Locks with same ID as my data array. No idea if this is performant but not at that stage yet.

Answer (score 0):

Multiprocessing.manager.Array comes with a built-in lock. Gotta switch to RawArray.

Have an list of locks. Before modifying an indice, acquire the lock for your array. Then release.

```
locks[i].acquire()
array[i,:]=0
locks[i].release()
```

As I said, if the array is a MultiProcessing.RawArray or similar, multiple processes can read or write simultaneously. For *some* types of Arrays, reading/writing to an Array is inherently atomic - the lock is essentially built in. Carefully research this before proceeding.

As for performance, indexing into a list is on the order of nanoseconds in Python, and acquiring and releasing a lock on the order of microseconds. It's not a huge issue.